# creating an inline update field using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've gotten stuck(again)

I have a table and one of the columns is a value that I want to be able to click, turn into an input field, then click again to change it back to just text.

I've gotten the first step done. It turns into an input field with a link to click and it uses the value that was previously in the td.

However, in writing the function to update the value and remove the input, I can't get it to fire at all. I've tried copying out the input field and hard coding that first step into the page and when I do that it does actually fire the click function. (I haven't finished writing this step as I wanted to get the function to fire first. Below is my code. Any help is overwhelmingly appreciated!

HTML:

```
<table>
<tr id="1"><td class="qty" set="0" >2</td></tr>
<tr id="2"><td class="qty" set="0" >2</td></tr>
<tr id="3"><td class="qty" set="0" >2</td></tr>
</table>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(".qty").click(function(){
    var value = $(this).text();
    var set =$(this).attr('set');
    if (set==0){
        $(this).html('<input type="text" name="quantity" value="'+value+'"><a href="#" class="update_qty">update</a> </span>');
        $(this).attr('set', '1');
    }
});

$(".update_qty").click(function(){
    alert("using this to check if it's firing");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use the [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function, otherwise the event won't be added to newly created elements.

```
$(".update_qty").live('click',function() {
   alert("check if firing");
});
```

Comment: brilliant! perfect! wonderful!  I think i've somehow been missing the live() function on a few other things. I shall go forth and learn more on this one! jquery api is my friend! :)  Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 1):

**demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/JEBaN/1/

some value

```
    <br><br>
    <a href='javascript:' id='toEdit'>To Edit Mode</a>
    <a href='javascript:' id='toView'>To View Mode</a>​


jQuery(function(){
        jQuery('#toEdit').click(_toEditMode);
        jQuery('#toView').click(_toViewMode);    
});

function _toEditMode()
{
    var _elm=jQuery('.converter');
    var _val= _elm.html();
    _elm.html('<input type="text" value="'+_val+'" />');
}

function _toViewMode()
{
    var _elm=jQuery('.converter');
    var _val= _elm.find('input').val();
    _elm.html(_val);
}

​
```

Comment: although that works, I'm wanting a way to make the view link as part of the actual edit function. thanks though!

Answer (score -1):

```
$(".update_qty").click(function(){
    $("qty").html("<p>whatever text you want</p>");
});
```